# C++ bitwise ops on double via long long pointer breaks output

Tags: c++, double, bit-manipulation

yes i know, making bitwise ops on double values seems like a bad idea, but i actually need it.

You don't need to read the next paragraph for my question, only for the curious of you guys:

I actually try a special mod to the Mozilla Tamarin (Actionscript Virtual Machine). In it, any object has the first 3 bits reserved for it's type (double is 7 for example). These bits reduce precision for primitive data types (int only 29 bits etc.). For my mod, i need to expand this area by 2 bits. This means, when you for example add 2 doubles, you need to set these last 5 bits to zero, do the math, then reset them on the result. so much for the why ^^

Now back to the code. 
Here a minimal example which shows a very similar problem:

```
double *d = new double; 
*d = 15.25; 
printf("float: %f\n", *d);

//forced hex output of double
printf("forced bitwise of double: ");
unsigned char * c = (unsigned char *) d;
int i;
for (i = sizeof (double)-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
     printf ("%02X ", c[i]);
}
printf ("\n");

//cast to long long-pointer, so that bitops become possible
long long * l = (long long*)d;
//now the bitops: 
printf("IntHex: %016X, float: %f\n", *l, *(double*)l); //this output is wrong!
*l = *l | 0x07; 
printf("last 3 bits set to 1: %016X, float: %f\n", *l, *d);//this output is wrong!
*l = *l | 0x18; 
printf("2 bits more set to 1: %016X, float: %f\n", *l, *d);//this output is wrong!
```

when running this in VisualStudio2008, the first output is correct. second too. 3rd yields 0 for both hex and float-representation, which is obviously wrong. 4th and 5th also zero for both hex and float, but the modified bits show in the hex-value. So i thought, maybe the typecast messed things up here. so 2 more outputs:

```
printf("float2: %f\n", *(double*)(long long*)d); //almost right
printf("float3: %f\n", *d); //almost right
```

well, they show 15.25, but it should be 15.2500000000000550670620214078. so i thought, hey, it's just the precision issue in the output. lets modify a bit further up:

```
*l = *l |= 0x10000000000;
printf("float4: %f\n", *d);
```

again, output is 15.25(0000), and not 15.2519531250000550670620214078. Weird enough, another forced hex output (see code above) shows no modification of d at all. so i tinkered a bit, and realized that bit 31 (0x80000000) is the last one i can set by hand. and holy moly, it actually has an effect on the output (15.250004)!

so, though i slightly strayed, still a lot of confusion. is printf broken? am i having a big/little-endian confusion here? am i accidently creating some kind of buffer overrun?

If anybody is interested, in the original problem (the tamarin thing, see above) it's pretty much inverse. there, the last three bits are already set (which represents a double). setting them to zero works fine (which is the original implementation). setting 2 more to zero has the same effect as above (overall value gets floored to zero). which by the way is not output-specific, but also math-ops seem to work with those floored values (mul of 2 values obtained like that results in 0).

Any help would be appreciated. 
Greetings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> well, they show 15.25, but it should be 15.2500000000000550670620214078

By default, `%f` displays 6 digits of precision, so you won't see the difference. You also need to specify that the first argument is `long long` rather than `int`, using the `ll` modifier; otherwise, it might print garbage. If you fix that and use a higher precision, such as `%.30f`, you should see the expected result:

```
printf("last 3 bits set to 1: %016llX, float: %.30f\n", *l, *d);
printf("2 bits more set to 1: %016llX, float: %.30f\n", *l, *d);

last 3 bits set to 1: 0000000000000007, float: 15.250000000000012434497875801753
2 bits more set to 1: 000000000000001F, float: 15.250000000000055067062021407764
```

> lets modify a bit further up:

```
*l = *l |= 0x10000000000;
printf("float4: %f\n", *d);
```

You have a rogue `=` giving undefined behaviour, so the value may or may not end up being modified (and the program may or may not crash, phone out for pizza, or destroy the universe). Also, if your compiler isn't C++11 compliant, the type of the integer literal might be no larger than `long`, which might only be 32 bits; in which case it will (probably) become zero.

Fixing those (and in my case, with your code as it is), I get the expected result:

```
*l = *l | 0x10000000000LL;  // just one assignment, and "LL" to force "long long"
printf("float4: %f\n", *d);


float4: 15.251953
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/1MgiQ) is a demonstration.

Comment: Thanks mike. that rogue = was actually a copy-paste-error, i found that while writing the question and failed to correct it here. The LL is something i didnt know before, so thanks for that.

whats weird is this: the moment i put in those %.30f in the printf's, they didnt show 0.0 anymore, but actually 15.25.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in the parameter of printf. If you pass a 8byte value you have to use 
%llx instead of %x.

use

```
printf("last 3 bits set to 1: %llX, float: %f\n", *l, *d);
*l = *l | 0x18; 
printf("2 bits more set to 1: %llX, float: %f\n", *l, *d);
```

and your code will work

Answer (score 0):

On 32 bit the constant can not be greater then long (32 bit) so you can not do that:

`*l |= 0x10000000000;`

You have to create a variable then shift it.

```
long long ll = 1;
ll <= 32;
*l |= ll;
```

Comment: @ManuelAmstutz: It's correct for C++03; that didn't define `long long`, so integer literals couldn't be larger than `long`, which is 32 bits on many platforms. In C++11, integer literals can have `long long` type if the value is too large for smaller types.

Comment: Ok my comment was very imprecise.
Sascha wrote that he is using VS2008. For all VC versions from 2003 - 2010
long long is an equivalent to __int64:

Comment: @ManuelAmstutz: I was talking about the constant (i.e. 0x10000000000) not the variable. I was not aware of the LL suffix.